# Android: Media Player Duration Issue

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

I have set:

```
mSeekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration()); // 8480
```

After completion of Audiofile, What I am getting is:

```
 player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
                    {
                        Log.e("onComplete>>", ""+mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

                        // mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() = 8192

                        Log.e("getDuration", ""+mediaPlayer.getDuration());

                        //  mediaPlayer.getDuration() = 8480

                       if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()>=mediaPlayer.getDuration())
                       {
                            // Why never get called???
                       }
                    }
                });
```

**So, Why is MediaPlayer's Current position never reaches the total duration of Audio file ?**

*Or technically we can say as:*

**Why Not?**

```
mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()==mediaPlayer.getDuration()
```

Why Always

**mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < mediaPlayer.getDuration()** 
in OnCompletion listener?

**For Example:**

I have a **Play** Symbol for starting the Player. Now when I press **play** symbol it will convert to **Pause** symbol.

I have a Maxduration of audiodfile.

Now I want to convert **Pause** symbol to **Play** Symbol when Audio file is played completely.
SO what I am doing is Checking:

```
if(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()>=mediaPlayer.getDuration())
{
       //  Convert Imagview from Pause to Play    
      // But never get called                   
}
```

Comment: What's output of `Log.i("onComplete>>", ""+mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        Log.i("getDuration", ""+mediaPlayer.getDuration());`

Comment: current position is always less than GetDuration.

Comment: Hmm.. I found an [issue thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38627) for same, but don't know if anyone found solution or explanation yet.. and [this](http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/mediaplayer-getcurrentposition-t20032.html), as well.

Comment: Yeah I will try it out by running another thread at the same time.But its still strange that OnCompletionListener() also don't provide correct value for getCurrentPosition().

Comment: I am having a hunch that in `onCompletion` the track is already completed, so may be reset to starting position, so its not same as total duration. But its just a wild guess. :)

Comment: No,I have tested getDuration in OnSeekBarchangeListener and the runnable itself that getCurrentPosition() never get >= getDuration()

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do some task on completion by checking `currentPoision` to duration, you can do below trick:

```
if(mediaPlayer.getDuration()-mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()<1000){//milliseconds
  new Handler().postDelayed(
     new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             // Convert Imageview from Pause to Play    
         }
     },1000); 
}
```